# Does ARM template support to create AAD applications/service principals?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Several resources, such as AKS clusters, require a service principal (AAD application) to be created. Can this be done via template? or only via the [`az ad sp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest) set of commands in the AZCLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ARM template does not support to create the service principal(AAD Application), ARM template is for azure resources in the subscription, the service principal(AAD Application) is under the AAD tenant, it is not the resource in the subscription.

For more details about ARM, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview).